# EditText cuts off text

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I’m working on my first app right now and have a slight XML problem. This is how my screen currently looks and as you can see the word “Invested” is cut in half.

[image: android screenshot]

Here is my code that is producing this behavior:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.quinnmchugh.networthcalculator.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPrincipal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/principal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPrincipal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="ex. 5,000"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblStartingSalary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/starting_salary"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtStartingSalary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="ex. 60,000"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAnnualReturn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/annual_return"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtAnnualReturn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="ex. 7%"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPercentOfIncome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/percent_of_income"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPercentOfIncome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="ex. 15%"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I need to fix to get the EditText to fully wrap itself and display the entire contents of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some padding to the element that is getting cut-off.  Something like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblPercentOfIncome"
    ...
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" />
```

Comment: So this would indicate that the `padding` doesn't get inherited and you must re-state it for each object?

Comment: It isn't 'inherited', but your parent container can contain it's own independent padding (that may or not be used by a child view).

Answer (score 0):

Append a new line "\n" to your text. This will always show all of your text.

Comment: This solution, although it works, seems like a "cheap hack". Is this the industry preferred way solving this problem?

Comment: Haha i'm not sure about industry preferred. I'm just an engineering student. But it worked out for me.

Comment: Definition of a 'Hack' is who wrote it (ie. if you wrote it, it is a hack, if I wrote it, is a a quick workaround).  I wouldn't do this, as Android will trim whitespace from front and end of your text - especially if it is resolved via Strings.xml.